# First two letters from words Regex in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to get the first upper and lower letter from each word from a string.

```
string<-"Programmation _ Is 2 Cool"
gsub("[^A-Z]", "", string)
gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", string)
```

The two results are :

```
"PIC"
"ProgrammationIsCool"
```

I would like to get :

```
"PrIsCo"
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If the first uppercase and the next lowercase letters must be extracted**, use

```
(\\b[A-Z][a-z])|.
```

or

```
(\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll})|.
```

The idea is to match and capture first uppercase and the following lowercase letters, and remove all the rest.

```
gsub("(\\b[A-Z][a-z])|.", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
```

Note that to remove newlines, you will need to pre-pend `(?s)` to the beginning of the pattern.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\\b[A-Z][a-z])` - Group 1 matching

  - `\\b` - a word boundary
  - `[A-Z][a-z]` - An uppercase ASCII letter followed with a lowercase ASCII letter (replace with `\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}` to match any Unicode uppercase-lowercase letters).
- `|` - or
- `.` - any character but a newline

Comment: I re-read the question, and now think the real regex  should be `(\\b[A-Z][a-z]?)|.` (or `(\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}?)|.`)

Comment: I edited the answer. Note that 1-letter words will be only accounted for if you put a `?` after the `[a-z]` (or `\\p{Ll}`)

Comment: sorry for constant bugging..but can't this question be interpreted as first uppercase and first lowercase which can be anywhere in string and not just in starting (_just a thought_)

Comment: @rock321987: No, *I am trying to get the first upper and lower letter from each word from a string*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah..maybe, i am overthinking